# How to use elastic search match query with keyword analyer with Java API

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello I'm new to Elastic Search and I'm trying to build an elastic search query using Java API. I have the following.

```
QueryBuilder findString = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("fieldOne", "foo bar").analyzer("keyword");
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.must(findString);
```

This return back nothing but I want it to return back all fieldOne that match "foo bar"

I know if I do

```
QueryBuilder findString = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("fieldOne", "foo bar");
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.must(findString);
```

this will return back any fieldOne that had "foo" or "bar" in it but I want it to equal exactly "foo bar"

I thought changing the analyzer to the keyword analyzer would work but it doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When you are specifying the analyzer at the search time, then that analyzer only defines how your query will be analyzed that is sent (here it is `"foo bar"`). This will not affect the way the term (`"foo bar"`) is indexed.**

If you have not explicitly defined any mapping then you need to add .keyword to the `fieldOne` field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after `fieldOne` field).

Try out this below code

```
QueryBuilder findString = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("fieldOne.keyword", "foo bar");
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.must(findString);
```

Comment: @angryHeo please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?